# How to download a 30GB file through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, download, httpclient, large-files, large-file-support

I have a URL which is a 30GB of file, I want to create a Javascript function which will download the file in user system through chuncks by chunck (1GB).
In simple term something like, 1GB of data gets downloaded first and stored in the user system in download folder and then second 1GB writes to the same file and so on.

I have below code but it uses browser memory to store all the chuncks before initiating a download.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            function downloadFileWithRange(url, sliceNumber) {
                const sliceSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

                const start = (sliceNumber - 1) * sliceSize;
                const end = sliceNumber * sliceSize - 1;

                const requestOptions = {
                    headers: {
                        'Range': `bytes=${start}-${end}`
                    }
                };

                fetch(url, requestOptions)
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.status === 206) {
                            return response.arrayBuffer();
                        } else {
                            console.error('Failed to download file. Status code:', response.status);
                        }
                    })
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log(`Downloaded slice ${sliceNumber} data:`, data);
                        chunks.push(new Blob([data]));
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                    });
            }

            document.getElementById("downloadLink1").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                for (let i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
                    downloadFileWithRange("URL", i);
                }
            });
```

Can this is doable without using node.js ?

I am expecting a solution which can download this large file without crashing the browser.

Comment: Yes, of course, it's possible without Node.js. You can use whatever backend you want. A browser extension could also work. AFAIK it's not possible in the frontend.

Comment: Consider just allowing the user to download it. So instead of having you having to deal with the large file with code, just delegate it to the browser. Browsers can already download and write large files to the disk without needing JS code to do it.

Comment: @jabba - I can not use the backend as the URL is a CDN URL and if we use the backend we would lose the benefits of what CDN offers in terms of latency offers to the end user.

Comment: In that case, I would say, it's impossible. The best you can do, is what VLAZ recommended. Don't use JavaScript. Let the user download the file.

Comment: Can't you use the usual technique of creating a hidden iframe and instructing the browser to grab the file there?

Comment: Are you doing this in case of disconnects?, If the CDN your storing the file supports HTTP range requests, and ETag (it been CDN would be very odd if it didn't).  Then your users should be fine just using the browsers built in down-loader, it should know how to resume.

Comment: @VLAZ - We are seeing downloading the file from the browser is error-prone and 50% of the time fails without completing for a file of 30GB, The CDN vendor we are using is suggesting using client side (javascript) data chunking to download in smaller chunks to make it stable and fast. which so far does not seem to be a doable solution.

Comment: Seen as the CDN provider is talking about downloading in chunck, then it supports ranges.  So you have nothing to worry about, it doesn't matter if 50% of the time it fails.  Eg. In chrome if a download fails, and all been well you will get a `resume` button, click this and it will continue.   You can test this effect here -> https://ash-speed.hetzner.com/  start this download, in Chrome you can click the pause button, and then click the play button to resume.  See if you can do the same from your CDN provider.

Comment: I would ask the vendor for a reference or documentation